# Getting data out of JSON in NodeJS results in undefined

Tags: json, node.js, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

So today I was writing a nodejs app to get data out of a website's API.So the API returns data in JSON. This is my code :

```
var processing = WooCommerce.get('orders?status='+type, function(err, data, 
res) {
  var result = res;
  JSON.stringify(result)
  console.log(result);
  result = result[0].meta_data;
  console.log(result);
  });
```

And this is my console log : (Sorry for the mess)

```
    [{"id":2977,"parent_id":0,"number":"2977","order_key":"wc_order_5a8bc4c350d54","created_via":"checkout","version":"3.0.5","status":"on-hold","currency":"INR","date_created":"2018-02-20T12:18:3
5","date_created_gmt":"2018-02-20T06:48:35","date_modified":"2018-02-20T12:18:41","date_modified_gmt":"2018-02-20T06:48:41","discount_total":"0.00","discount_tax":"0.00","shipping_total":"0.00
","shipping_tax":"0.00","cart_tax":"0.00","total":"40.00","total_tax":"0.00","prices_include_tax":false,"customer_id":342,"customer_ip_address":"103.104.77.159","customer_user_agent":"mozilla\
/5.0 (linux; android 6.0.1; le x526 build\/iixosop5801910121s) applewebkit\/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome\/64.0.3282.137 mobile safari\/537.36","customer_note":"","billing":{"first_name":"
Fahad","last_name":"Khan","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"Delhi","state":"DL","postcode":"","country":"IN","email":"shimail786@gmail.com","phone":"8745076002"},"shipping":{"
first_name":"","last_name":"","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","postcode":"","country":""},"payment_method":"paytm-qr","payment_method_title":"Pay with Paytm QR"
,"transaction_id":"","date_paid":null,"date_paid_gmt":null,"date_completed":null,"date_completed_gmt":null,"cart_hash":"0119311d11c4978ecc7bf6f59b53586f","meta_data":[{"id":91320,"key":"_billi
ng_stl","value":"https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/tradeoffer\/new\/?partner=452464312&token=Gq27CMGc"},{"id":91321,"key":"billing_stl","value":"https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/tradeoffer\/new\/?par
tner=452464312&token=Gq27CMGc"},{"id":91324,"key":"_woocs_order_rate","value":"1"},{"id":91325,"key":"_woocs_order_base_currency","value":"INR"},{"id":91326,"key":"_woocs_order_currency_change
d_mannualy","value":"0"}],"line_items":[{"id":1641,"name":"MAG-7 | Silver (Factory New)","product_id":2972,"variation_id":0,"quantity":1,"tax_class":"","subtotal":"40.00","subtotal_tax":"0.00"
,"total":"40.00","total_tax":"0.00","taxes":[],"meta_data":[],"sku":"","price":40}],"tax_lines":[],"shipping_lines":[],"fee_lines":[],"coupon_lines":[],"refunds":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"
https:\/\/ezpz-skins.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/orders\/2977"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/ezpz-skins.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/orders"}],"customer":[{"href":"https:\/\/ezpz-skins.com\/wp-json\/w
c\/v2\/customers\/342"}]}},{"id":2976,"parent_id":0,"number":"2976","order_key":"wc_order_5a8bc2fabf6d8","created_via":"checkout","version":"3.0.5","status":"on-hold","currency":"INR","date_cr
eated":"2018-02-20T12:10:58","date_created_gmt":"2018-02-20T06:40:58","date_modified":"2018-02-20T12:11:02","date_modified_gmt":"2018-02-20T06:41:02","discount_total":"0.00","discount_tax":"0.
00","shipping_total":"0.00","shipping_tax":"0.00","cart_tax":"0.00","total":"95.00","total_tax":"0.00","prices_include_tax":false,"customer_id":342,"customer_ip_address":"103.104.77.159","cust
omer_user_agent":"mozilla\/5.0 (linux; android 6.0.1; le x526 build\/iixosop5801910121s) applewebkit\/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome\/64.0.3282.137 mobile safari\/537.36","customer_note":""
,"billing":{"first_name":"Fahad","last_name":"Khan","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"Delhi","state":"DL","postcode":"","country":"IN","email":"shimail786@gmail.com","phone":"
8745076002"},"shipping":{"first_name":"","last_name":"","company":"","address_1":"","address_2":"","city":"","state":"","postcode":"","country":""},"payment_method":"paytm-qr","payment_method_
title":"Pay with Paytm QR","transaction_id":"","date_paid":null,"date_paid_gmt":null,"date_completed":null,"date_completed_gmt":null,"cart_hash":"ca6b663ea1f4b4c7ed65b9fd39acc2cb","meta_data":
[{"id":91268,"key":"_billing_stl","value":"https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/tradeoffer\/new\/?partner=452464312&token=1m7SCUVf"},{"id":91269,"key":"billing_stl","value":"https:\/\/steamcommunity.
com\/tradeoffer\/new\/?partner=452464312&token=1m7SCUVf"},{"id":91272,"key":"_woocs_order_rate","value":"1"},{"id":91273,"key":"_woocs_order_base_currency","value":"INR"},{"id":91274,"key":"_w
oocs_order_currency_changed_mannualy","value":"0"}],"line_items":[{"id":1639,"name":"SG 553 | Tiger Moth (Field Tested)","product_id":911,"variation_id":0,"quantity":1,"tax_class":"","subtotal
":"42.00","subtotal_tax":"0.00","total":"42.00","total_tax":"0.00","taxes":[],"meta_data":[],"sku":"","price":42},{"id":1640,"name":"Glock-18 | Bunsen Burner (Factory New)","product_id":532,"v
ariation_id":0,"quantity":1,"tax_class":"","subtotal":"53.00","subtotal_tax":"0.00","total":"53.00","total_tax":"0.00","taxes":[],"meta_data":[{"id":4861,"key":"_woocs_order_rate","value":"1"}
,{"id":4862,"key":"_woocs_order_base_currency","value":"INR"},{"id":4863,"key":"_woocs_order_currency_changed_mannualy","value":"0"}],"sku":"","price":53}],"tax_lines":[],"shipping_lines":[],"
fee_lines":[],"coupon_lines":[],"refunds":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/ezpz-skins.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/orders\/2976"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/ezpz-skins.com\/wp-json\/wc\
/v2\/orders"}],"customer":[{"href":"https:\/\/ezpz-skins.com\/wp-json\/wc\/v2\/customers\/342"}]}}]
undefined
```

So I realize (after reading tons of questions on StackOverflow) that my data is an array. That's why I have added the `result = result[0].meta_data;` But that gives me `undefined` (notice it at the end of log). Also if I remove `.meta_data` , it just returns `[`, the very first character.

Where am I going wrong ? I'm kinda new to all this and am still learning, so please explain :)

Comment: Remove `JSON.stringify` part, as you are changing JavaScript object into string. If this is a real code - you don't assign stringify to anything, try deleting it and adding: `result = JSON.parse(result);`

Comment: @Sindis I tried removing it, it still results in undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'res' is in string format so instead of JSON.stringify() use JSON.parse() so that it will be converted back into Javascript object, then try consoling the result as shown below and try to access meta_data after that.

```
var processing = WooCommerce.get('orders?status='+type, function(err, data, 
    res) {
      var result = JSON.parse(res);
      console.log(result[0]);
      result = result[0].meta_data;
      console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! But I had already tried this before, I remember it crashing and giving me an error about something related to obj.